# What caused the java.lang.InternalError (it extends VirtualMachineError)

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, classloader, internal

When I tried to do SVN synchronize I got this error. I wonder why it has happen, any ideas? It works great after restarting eclipse, but I wonder what could cause it and how its possible that the jar was not found.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2011-12-09 14:22:15.534
!MESSAGE SVN: '0x00000107: Synchronizing' operation finished with error
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2011-12-09 14:22:15.534
!MESSAGE Synchronize operation failed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.InternalError
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:755)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:221)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getBootstrapResource(ClassLoader.java:1151)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1000)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:998)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemResource(ClassLoader.java:1101)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.i(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.g(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b$1.run(DashoA13*..)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.<clinit>(DashoA13*..)
    at javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(DashoA13*..)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.getKeyAgreement(JsseJce.java:241)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.JsseJce.isEcAvailable(JsseJce.java:158)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite$KeyExchange.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:271)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuite.isAvailable(CipherSuite.java:143)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.buildAvailableCache(CipherSuiteList.java:210)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.CipherSuiteList.getDefault(CipherSuiteList.java:233)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.init(SSLSocketImpl.java:508)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:451)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:73)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:186)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:327)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:275)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:263)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:516)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:98)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:999)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getRepositoryUUID(DAVRepository.java:146)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.createRepository(SVNBasicClient.java:342)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNBasicClient.createRepository(SVNBasicClient.java:330)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.wc.SVNStatusClient.doStatus(SVNStatusClient.java:338)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.status(SVNClientImpl.java:300)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl.SVNClientImpl.status(SVNClientImpl.java:282)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector.status(SVNKitConnector.java:341)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.extension.factory.ThreadNameModifier.status(ThreadNameModifier.java:608)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.local.RemoteStatusOperation$2.run(RemoteStatusOperation.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doSubTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.local.RemoteStatusOperation.runImpl(RemoteStatusOperation.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.LoggedOperation.run(LoggedOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.synchronize.AbstractSVNSubscriber.findChanges(AbstractSVNSubscriber.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.synchronize.AbstractSVNSubscriber$UpdateStatusOperation$2.run(AbstractSVNSubscriber.java:349)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doSubTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.synchronize.AbstractSVNSubscriber$UpdateStatusOperation.runImpl(AbstractSVNSubscriber.java:347)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.LoggedOperation.run(LoggedOperation.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.synchronize.AbstractSVNSubscriber.refresh(AbstractSVNSubscriber.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.synchronize.UpdateSubscriber.refresh(UpdateSubscriber.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.subscribers.Subscriber.refresh(Subscriber.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.subscribers.SubscriberMergeContext.refresh(SubscriberMergeContext.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.team.core.mapping.provider.SynchronizationContext.refresh(SynchronizationContext.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.synchronize.RefreshModelParticipantJob.doRefresh(RefreshModelParticipantJob.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.synchronize.RefreshParticipantJob.run(RefreshParticipantJob.java:309)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.synchronize.RefreshModelParticipantJob.run(RefreshModelParticipantJob.java:117)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/jce.jar
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(URLClassPath.java:644)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.access$600(URLClassPath.java:540)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(URLClassPath.java:607)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(URLClassPath.java:599)
    at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:753)
    ... 69 more
```

**no, it always works. just one time it did not.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the JDK source code of [sun.misc.URLClassPath](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java.html) and [sun.misc.FileURLMapper](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FileURLMapper.java.html), there is code in FileURLMapper.exists() that does the following:

```
public boolean exists() {
    String path = getPath();
    File f = new File (path);
    return f.exists();
}
```

Assuming nothing crazy has happened like the jce.jar file was actually deleted (such as through upgrading version of Java while Eclipse is running), the File.exists() call might fail because of some other reason (out of memory / file descriptors possibly?  On Unix file.exists() eventually calls the [stat/stat64 function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28Unix%29))

Comment: I agree, a file descriptor leak leading to file-not-found is the most likely culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Drilling down to the [code found here](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java.html#line.753) the things I can see: Invocation of `sun.misc.URLClassPath.JarLoader.ensureOpen()` at line 753 leads to `InternalError` raised at line [755](http://javasourcecode.org/html/open-source/jdk/jdk-6u23/sun/misc/URLClassPath.java.html#line.755).

The method is like as below:

```
private void ensureOpen() throws IOException {
    if (jar == null) {
        try {
            java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction() {
                        public Object run() throws IOException {
                            ....
                        }
                    });
        } catch (java.security.PrivilegedActionException pae) {
            throw (IOException) pae.getException(); // this exception is thrown
        }
    }
}
```

Here `java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedExceptionAction<T>)` is a native method. Documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#doPrivileged%28java.security.PrivilegedExceptionAction%29).

As it can be understood from document, that `error` is thrown possibly for chekced exception that occur while processing `public Object run() throws IOException {`.

Comment: but why was this exception thrown? any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Check this file

/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20/jre/lib/jce.jar

probably your eclipse tries to authenticate with repository but lacks classes needed to process and perform auth.

Comment: ¿Do you have more than one jdk installed?

Comment: yup, just guessed it couldn't find it for a reason... well, gave up, sorry